# What is the terminology and technology used to assign multiple IP addresses to a single host name?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, host

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Point Multiple IP Addresses to a Single Host Name](https://serverfault.com/questions/69836/point-multiple-ip-addresses-to-a-single-host-name)

I want a host name such as "www.dacracot.org", to point to multiple IP addresses, "1.2.3.4" and "1.2.3.5".

Is this set up by my DNS people?  What is the correct terminology?

Comment: I call BS, that is in no way the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called Round robin DNS; Yes it is set up at the DNS level. All you have to do is add mutiple A records to your Nameserver.  Be fore warned, It is not the best load balancing/redundant   solution. Have a look at Even's post here for more info [Uneven round-robin DNS (i.e. not round-robin)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/92601/uneven-round-robin-dns-i-e-not-round-robin/92608#92608)

Comment: So I have redundant load balancing set up behind the two addresses I want pointed to as the same host.  Will clients switch to 1.2.3.5 if 1.2.3.4 goes down?

Comment: not very likely to happen